# S3 in Bucket/Folder preview files and download them, but not let save changes, with NetDrive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I have a Bucket with a folder, I want to give read permissions, preview but do not allow saving changes, download the file from NetDrive, is it viable as a local drive?

The bucket has a folder that is shared but it must allow viewing the document, but not saving the changes and if the user needs it, they can download it, without affecting the original.

Creating a policy like this works but allows the user to open the file and allows the user to save changes and that's what I don't want:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::desision-hseq"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "operation/",
                        "operation/formats",
                        "operation/procedures"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::desision-hseq"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "operation/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::desision-hseq/operation/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement is granting `s3:*` actions, which means the user can do *anything* in that folder including **uploading, downloading and deleting objects**:

```json
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::desision-hseq/operation/*"
            ]
        }
```

If you only want them to 'read' objects from that folder (which is both Open and Download), then only grant an action of: `s3:GetObject`

```json
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::desision-hseq/operation/*"
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer I add something, it is possible to delete the temporary one once the main file is closed, for example I have the text.xlsx file when it is opened a .tmp is created although it does not allow the modification to be saved, the temporary one does save it but it does not delete when original file is closed, is it workable?

Comment: I see that you are using NetDrive, which 'mounts' an Amazon S3 bucket as a local drive. Therefore, programs will attempt to create files on that 'drive' with the expectation that there are no restrictions on what they can write. This creates a problem when you wish to restrict what NetDrive can do on the bucket (eg when the program wants to delete the file, but you have not granted NetDrive permission to delete objects). If you have used the above permissions, then NetDrive only has permission to `ListBucket` and `GetObject`, so it should not be able to `PutObject` to create any objects.